# Laravel - Eloquent ORM Search function

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to create a function  that will search all the records within a table from a single search input. I have done a simple search which gets the value from input and within a foreach loop i am receiving the array of results related to the search.

Controller function

```
public function getSearch(){
    $input = Input::get('search');

    $validator = Validator::make($input, array(
            'search' => 'required'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()){
        die('error');
    } else {
      $search_terms = explode(' ', $input);

      foreach($search_terms as $term)
      {
          $query = Upload::where('filename', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%');
      }

      $results = $query->get();
      die($results);
    }
}
```

In validator I have only one argument to make it required and passed within the array.

```
'search' => 'required'
```

I assume that the reason i am getting this error is because I am only passing one argument in validator's array?

```
ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, string given, called in /www/assetlibr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 211 and defined
```

Update: Because the validator is not the best practice here, instead I removed the validator and added an if statement like

```
if(Input::has('search'))
```

and is now working perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first argument passed to make need to be array. you give string..

look at the docs:
http://laravel.com/docs/validation

change your code to this:

```
    $serach = Input::get('search');

    $validator = Validator::make(
                array(
            'search' => $search,
                ), 
                array(
            'search' => 'required'
                )
     );
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I didn't notice that I am only passing the string from the input. I got that working, but didn't worked as I was expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Validator requires two arrays, one for data and other one for validation rules, so yes, you are missing it there in `Validator::make()` call. Here is how you should perform the validation:

```
$input = array('search' => Input::get('search'));

$validator = Validator::make($input, array(
        'search' => 'required'
    )
);
```